# Filter data with dynamic and nested filter conditions using Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, lodash

I want to filter my product data with multiple as well as Dynamic filter conditions.
First my raw data format is:

```
[{

 ...,

 "_source": {

  ...,

  "categories": [
   "home",
   "office"
  ],

  ...,

  "attributes": {
    "colors": [
      "Red-White-Blue",
      "Orange-Red-Black"
    ]
  },

  ...,

 }
}]
```

Now, I have another dynamic object whose key-value pair is generated at run time. The object is:

```
{  
   selectedFilters: {
     categories: ["home", "office", "public"],
     colors: ["Red-White-Blue", "Orange-Red-Black", "Blue"],
     ...
   }
}
```

Here, maybe categories array be there, or maybe not. Like wise, the keyvalue pair is generated dynamically.

Now, I want to loop through all the keys from `selectedFilters` object and find them in their respective array from my raw data.

Let say if selectedFilters contains `categories` as `home` and `colors` contain `white`, then all the product with home `category` and white `colors` should be returned from main product data. If there is no value in `colors`, then it should return all product data with `category` as home, likewise if `color` is white and `categories` is empty, then it should return all white color products no matter what category.

How can I achieve this with or without Lodash?

Comment: you better give more complete input and expected output because your question is not very clear

Comment: I've already provided proper input and expected output. Please read carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below code worked for dynamic keys in searchFilters. And then, I'm filtering data from the product data.

```
let keys = Object.keys(this.selectedFilters);

keys.forEach(function(filterKey) {

  let filterdProducts = _.filter(self.products, function(o) {

  let flg = false;
  let searchFilterKey = self.selectedFilters[filterKey];
  searchFilterKey.forEach(function(sKey) {
    let ind = o._source[filterKey].indexOf(sKey)
    if (ind > 0)
      flg = true;
  })
  if (flg)
    return o;
});

self.filteredProducts = filterdProducts

});
```